# Installing Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS on an old Mac Mini (Mid 2011) and getting an EFI error. NOT dual boot. Clean wipe all Ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, uefi, disk

I am wiping the entire disk and attempting to install Ubuntu on a Mac Mini.  When i choose erase the entire disk and do the work for me it comes back with:

"No EFI System Partition was found.  This system will likely not be able to boot successfully, and the installation process may fail.

Please go back and add an EFI System Partition, or continue at your own risk."

I go back and delete the large /dev/sda ext4 and created a 512MB EFI and then re-created the large /dev/sda ext 4 and now the EFI is on SDA2 and the large volume is SDA 3 and I get " No root file system is defined.
Please correct this from the partitioning menu."

Any suggestions on drive setup?

Thanks in advance,
Samsonbull

Answer (score 1):

You could split your disk in three partitions using **Something else** during installation when Disk configuration step will come:

- EFI, 512Mb size as you did, ESP and boot marks should be set
- `/`, 40Gb size, but depends of your overall disk capacity and OS usage
- `/home` partition the left space

Comment: 60GB a bit big for /. usual recommendation around 20 to 30GBs, plus the rest for /home.

Comment: @crip659 Ok. Now on my laptop I have used 20Gb. Also, this is not bad. You could create a `vm` folder in root and give it user's ownership and use its space when required for virtualization or whatever you want). Also, big disk consuming operations as release upgrades, kernels compilations or whatever will not worry you:)